# iPhone simulator failed to install the application

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

I have an account on a university computer network, and whenever i try to Build and Go with an application in Xcode, i get this error :

`Error from debugger: Failed to launch simulated application: iPhone Simulator failed to install the application`

The SDK is installed in /Developer as expected and i have created my project directory on a local hard drive... I think the problem is the location of my ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator directory, my entire ~/Library directory is aliased to a different location.

Can i change the location of the iPhone Simulator directory from within Xcode?

Or any other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: do you have access to the console application on this machine? If so, see if there are any additional clues posted to console while trying to launch sim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone Simulator does not support operating on remote home directories.  If you check the readme during the installation of the iPhone sdk it says the following:

> "The iPhone Simulator does not support network home directories"

Bum deal, but I'd bet that your average University mac would have network home directories.